# ajax MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter is not present]

Tags: ajax

I have the error :
MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'employee' for method parameter type Employee is not present]
I don't understand why.

```js
 

   function createEmployee() {
       const employee = {};
            employee.id = document.getElementById("detailledMatriculeDataLabelId").value;
            employee.firstName = document.getElementById("detailledFirstNameDataLabelId").value;
            employee.lastName = document.getElementById("detailledLastNameDataLabelId").value;
            employee.address = document.getElementById("detailledAddressDataLabelId").value;
            employee.title = document.getElementById("detailledTitleDataLabelId").value;
            employee.managerId =1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/create' ,
            data : employee,
            type: 'POST ',
            success: function(result) {
                document.location.reload()
            },
            error: function() {
               console.log ("creation failed ");
            }
        });
    }
```

'''

```
@PostMapping(path="/create") // Map ONLY POST Requests
public String createEmployee (@RequestParam Employee employee) {
    // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
    // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request
    System.err.println("createEmployee");

    employeesRepository .save(employee);
    return "/index";
}
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

I have found many posts, and after many tries got it:

for ajax

```js
        data: JSON.stringify(employee),
        contentType: "application/json",
```

and for the java code: replace the @RequestParam with @RequestBody.
AI does not understand why if someone has the answer ...